# Reading un-sampled reports in Google Analytics using Management API

Tags: php, google-analytics

Accessing un-sampled reports requires the Report Id as input.

How do I list ids of all the un-sampled reports?

Answer (score 1):

Doing an [Unsampledreport.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports/list)  will return a list of the unsampled reports.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/accountId/webproperties/webPropertyId/profiles/profileId/unsampledReports

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#unsampledReports",
  "username": string,
  "totalResults": integer,
  "startIndex": integer,
  "itemsPerPage": integer,
  "previousLink": string,
  "nextLink": string,
  "items": [
    management.unsampledReports Resource
  ]
}
```

Comment: well that's kinda a given you need to be authenticated to access the data